# bash: add column if row name is repeated

Tags: bash

I have a file with several variables in rows and values of these variables in columns. Some rows are repeated and only contain data for some of the columns (e.g. is the example below, the second time "A" appears, it only contains data in columns S1 and S2)

Example:

```
Variable S1 S2 S3
A        3  5  6
B        4  5  6
A        some_string another_string
C        2  5  6
```

What I want is to add another (or several) columns that contain the data from  the repeated row

Output example:

```
Variable S1 S2 S3 new_column1 new_column2
A        3  5  6  some_string another_string
B        4  5  6
C        2  5  6
```

I am thinking that something like the code below could get me there, but it's still erroneous and I'm not sure if it is even possible to do in bash?
My code would only be able to create ONE new column and I don't know how I can add the data to that new column.
I found those pieces of code in an other question that was similar, but not quite what I want, so I would appreciate any help!

```
awk 'NR==1{$5="new_column";print;next} seen[$1]++ {$5=$2}' file
```

Comment: `... $5+=$2...` or maybe you'll have to use `$5=$5 " " $2` . Good luck.

Comment: Do you know perl, python or PHP?  I would build an associative array where the index is the variable name, and the value is an array with the column values.  As you read your input file line per line, you bild the associative array, and when done, dump the associative array into the output file.  It can be done in bash as well, it's just I find it easier to do in other languages when it comes to manipulating arrays.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know any perl, python or PHP.  Do you think this is possible in Matlab also, and if so, what exactly do you mean by "associative array"?